# Efficiency of mouse listener on JButton

Tags: java, swing, graphics, time-complexity, jcomponent

Let say I created `n` JButtons and place them randomly in a JFrame and I add a mouse listener on each JButton.

**My question is**:
When I click on any one of the JButtons, does Java check through all JButtons to determine which button am I clicking (worst case: `n checks`) OR it does not need to check through all buttons (worst case: `1 check`)?

*The reason I ask this is because I am trying to interact with 2DGraphics and I know one of the ways to check whether I click on a particular Shape is by checking through all Shapes whether that Shape contains my current mouse coordinates. So if I draw 10 shapes, my worst case would be 10. Honestly speaking, I feel that kind of inefficient.*

So I was wondering how does JComponent handles an actionEvent. By checking through all JComponents or they don't?

If they don't, how does Java determines which button was clicked?

Comment: In your case, if you're using a JButton with a button listener, the mouse listener is redundant since the JButton is going to be throwing its own button pressed event which identifies the button being pressed. Are you perhaps making this problem more difficult than it needs to be?

Comment: @MarsAtomic That was just a what-if scenario. You can treat it as there is only actionListener for each button. So what would the efficiency be for the actionListener?

Comment: What I'm getting at is that you're doing an apples to oranges comparison. JButton will throw its own event, letting you know the event source. Presumably, your Shapes do not, so you're left with iterating through them as you described. If you subclassed them and implemented ActionListener, you could throw ActionEvents from each specific subclassed Shape. Honestly, I don't know *exactly* how Java determines which component throws which event, but as much of an idiot as I am, I know there's a way to get what you want in the end. ;)

Comment: For practical purposes all we can say is that it's efficient enough. If it's just a theoretical question about how this could be achieved in a hypothetical GUI, the first thing you can do is observe that all your shapes are rectangles, aligned neatly to the x-y axis. This means that you can store all your shapes in two maps, one for the X and one for the Y coordinate. If you have a coordinate pair and you want to find out which element is under it, you do a lookup in one map, then in the other and take the intersection of the two sets.

Comment: ...of course you can "cheat" with the intersection too, as you will sort them by z-index first, then look for the first element that is present in both.

Comment: @biziclop I am aware of the approach you mentioned. If I interpreted what you said correctly, it is implemented some what like a grid system. Based on x,y pos of the mouse, I determine which grid, and thus knowing which Shape was clicked. However I am still curious whether Java does loop through all components when only one of them was clicked. I read through many available API and tutorials, but none mention how Java actionListener works internally. Sometimes I am even curious whether there is an individual thread dedicated for each component.

Comment: The general answer to your question is "yes". The Event Dispatching Thread will dispatch the MouseEvent to all the components for processing. I don't have the extract code in front of me so I'm not sure if the EDT makes the decisions or the components themselves do

Comment: Oh, and as general feedback, don't use MouseListener's with buttons, use a ActionListener, the user may choose to press the action key to activate the button and not the mouse ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your feedback, I look forward for your reply here and if possible a solution. There are many veteran coders here and IMO you are one of them :)

Comment: The real question here is, have you seen any kind of issue related to an increasing number of buttons?

Comment: @MadProgrammer So there is indeed an individual thread dedicated for each created component? So 10 components, 10 threads?

Comment: No, there is a SINGLE thread for everything, the EDT processes the Event Queue

Comment: @MadProgrammer ...and takes care of the drawing too.

Comment: @MadProgrammer `The real question here is, have you seen any kind of issue related to an increasing number of buttons?` I wonder on this question too. I once tested with thousands of buttons, but doesn't seem to affect the eventHandling. But my "test" might be inaccurate. So does increasing number of buttons affect the performance (in terms of event handling)?

Comment: *"Honestly speaking, I feel that kind of inefficient."*  I feel you're being confused by Premature Optimization.  Only worry about this sort of stuff if the app. is beginning to slow down and then, only then, run an optimization tool to ascertain ***where*** it is slowing down.  But just on the subject of *"mouse listener on JButton"* ..can you hear my teeth grinding?  A `JButton` should have an `ActionListener`.  The action listener will respond (fire) when the user clicks a button with the mouse, and it will **also fire** when the user tabs to the button and activates it using the keyboard.

Comment: It "seems" that when a core event is generated (mouse/key), the event has the AWT component which generated the event referenced as the source.  This "appears" to happen before the event is pushed onto the Event Queue, this means that the EDT targets the component directly and dispatches the event to it directly for processing. Because we're dealing with lightweight components (which don't have a native peer of there own), the events need to be "retargeted" to the Swing component.  In the case of mouse clicked, the container uses the component in which mouse was last "over"

Comment: The short answer is, it's complicated, but there does seem to be attempts to make the process more efficent

Comment: http://ftp.cs.duke.edu/~edels/Papers/1983-J-05-RectangleIntersections:PartII.pdf
Using that data structure, you can very efficiently find the rectangles that intersect with a point.

Comment: @Joonazan Thanks for the link, I will read up on that ;)